# How to pass div to the while loop, asp.net c#

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net, facebook

I am creating a social network website as facebook, but that website has an error with posing status , i used following code to post status.This code is on page load,

```
Label1.Text = Session["Email"].ToString();
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        //load data
        string db = "";
        db = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(db);
        con.Open();
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Name,Status FROM [PhotoStatusProfile] WHERE Email = @Email";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", Session["Email"].ToString());
            cmd.Connection = con;
            SqlDataReader dr;
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            string status = "";
            string name = "";

            while (dr.Read())
            {


                System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl div = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");
                Label nameLabel = new Label();
                status += dr["Status"].ToString();
                name += dr["name"].ToString();
                nameLabel.Text = name;
                Label statusLabel = new Label();
                statusLabel.Text = status;
                div.Controls.Add(nameLabel);

                div.Controls.Add(statusLabel);
                container.Controls.Add(div);


            }

            con.Close();
            }
```

I am passing value to a div which name is container. 
When i write a status saying hi,and click the post button but nothing happen, then i refresh the page, and it has [posted like this](https://scontent-b-lhr.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpf1/v/t1.0-0/10382729_615983818507134_7629598189703268546_n.jpg?efg=eyJpIjoiYiJ9&oh=986008501879831ae4625d01ce95a7d9&oe=5503914E)
2nd time i do the same thing saying hello, [this is the result of it.](https://scontent-b-lhr.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpf1/v/t1.0-0/1456753_615983821840467_926687506400648266_n.jpg?efg=eyJpIjoiYiJ9&oh=46b6b24316389f97c0242a7d728fb34b&oe=54FB791C)

This is container. it's a name of a div tag

```
<div id="container" runat="server"> </div>
```

This is post button event

```
 string inserQuery = "insert into PhotoStatusProfile(Name,Status,Email) values (@Name,@Status,@e)";
            SqlCommand commm = new SqlCommand(inserQuery, conn);
            commm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", ProfileName.Text);
            commm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status",TextBox1.Text);
            commm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@e", Label1.Text);



            commm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I want to post the status for down to down,
Could anybody tell me , what should i do to prevent this errors. Thaks

Comment: /OT wishing you success. Tried something similar but I had to delete it because it didn't take off :)

Comment: what should i delete it?

Comment: What's in you Post button's click event?

Comment: have a look at my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you to do the following re-factoring to your code.

1. Extract the code between following if block in your `Page_Load` and create a method called `LoadData()`.

   if(!IsPostBack)
    { 
         LoadData(); 
    }
2. Then in your Post button's click event call this `LoadData()` method again just after saving your new post to the database.
3. Instead of Labels to display values use `DIV`s (I mean nameLabel and statusLabel)
4. Also add following style to these `DIV`s

   style="float:left;"

This is how you'd add it in code behind

```
div.Style.Add("float", "left");
```

**UPDATE 1**

Here's how you'd add DIVs instead of Labels.

```
HtmlGenericControl divContainer = new HtmlGenericControl("div");

            HtmlGenericControl nameDiv = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
            // Not sure why you concatenate Name and Status here. I'll just use one value per each row
            // status += dr["Status"].ToString();
            // name += dr["name"].ToString();
            nameDiv.InnerText = dr["name"].ToString();
            nameDiv.Style.Add("float", "left");
            divContainer.Controls.Add(nameDiv);

            HtmlGenericControl statusDiv = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
            statusDiv.InnerText = dr["Status"].ToString();
            statusDiv.Style.Add("float", "left");
            divContainer.Controls.Add(statusDiv);

            container.Controls.Add(div);
```

**UPDATE 2**

Since you've adopted @mybirthname solution (using a `Repeater`) I'll just give you the design you want based on DIVs.

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="Repeater1">
       <ItemTemplate>
            <%--This is your template--%>
            <div style="margin-top: 5px;">
            <div style="padding: 2px; border: 1px solid black; background-color:Silver; display:table; width:600px;">
              <div style="float:left;">
                <div style="padding: 4px">
                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/my-avatar.PNG" /> <%--Give the correct path to your image--%>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                <div style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; padding-top: 4px;">
                    <%#Eval("name") %>                    
                    <div style="float:right; font-size: 10px;">9:00 am</div> <%--If you need to have a time stamp for each entry make use of this div--%>
                </div>
                <div style="width:500px;"><%#Eval("Status") %></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <%--End template--%>
    </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: where should i create this LoadData() method? should i create it in page_Load method?? and tell me i want to post these status to vertically. but these are posting horizontally ? how to get new line?

Comment: How can you create another method in Page_Load??? It should be a private method in your page's code behind. And, follow the other instructions and you'd get your posts vertically

Comment: hey friend. Instead of Labels to display values use DIVs (I mean nameLabel and statusLabel) should i create div object behalf of creating Label nameLabel = new Label(); these?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant

Comment: I want to post these things [likes this](https://scontent-b-lhr.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xap1/v/t1.0-0/10403710_1500118730277703_5227366070586246939_n.jpg?efg=eyJpIjoiYiJ9&oh=6afcc68c2f7e1c866777f8673a68a413&oe=54FEA4DF), I want to get posts vertically, I know i should use div than using label, but i don't know how to create object likes label. help me friend, thanks

Comment: malli lankaweda? :) Wait I'll post again

Comment: ah ow ow :D mata a code eka hoyala denna puluwanda.

Comment: I'm about to go home after work. I'll post a working sample later. For the time being have a look at the update to my answer.

Comment: [This is what](https://scontent-b-lhr.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xap1/v/t1.0-9/10405635_1500135106942732_3405316026992011431_n.jpg?oh=7a5f0f9013284e7b59204d5a1abafc9c&oe=5501AED9) i want friend,When i am posting these, those should be displayed like that, do u have a code for this?

Comment: Have a look at my second update. It'll give you the design you want.

Comment: Thanks ayya, but i did it using repeater control, :D

Comment: Yes I know. Update 3 in my answer gives the UI design you want. Did it using Divs.

Comment: This is for your Repeater solution you've used. Have a look. Just copy and paste.

Comment: No worries. If you are creating a chat app try to use Ajax and avoid any postbacks to the server when you press the Post button. And, the reason for using DIVs is because it's easy to use CSS for styling. Have fun with the app.

Comment: Friend, can i add ajax for this repeater control? if i use ajax,how would be this code? could you embed ajax functions for this code (Update 2)

Answer (score 0):

From what I see you are adding the div to container and `nameLabel`, `StatusLabel` to div on every iteration of the `DataReader`. Probably this is not your intention, You want to add them once, because you are storing in `status` all values of Status row.

```
        while (dr.Read())
        {       
            status += dr["Status"].ToString();
            name += dr["name"].ToString();
        }

        System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl div = new 
               System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");
        container.Controls.Add(div);

        Label nameLabel = new Label();
        nameLabel.Text = name;
        div.Controls.Add(nameLabel);

        Label statusLabel = new Label();
        statusLabel.Text = status;
        div.Controls.Add(statusLabel);
```

Also it will be good idea to put some ID to the labels. **I advice you to put labels and div always and just make them visible false if there are no values in them.**

Also if you add dynamically controls do it always in [CreateChildControls()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.createchildcontrols%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

**EDIT:** For what you want(written in my comments) you need a repeater. Check this tutorial in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zzx23804(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
<div id="container">
   <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="Repeater1">
       <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="yourDivClass">
                <asp:Label runat="server"> <%#Eval("Status") %> </asp:Label>
                <asp:Label runat="server"> <%#Eval("name") %> </asp:Label>
            </div>
       </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

And in the code behind in `Page_Load` method:

```
if(!PostBack)
{
    //in data set you will have dataTable with all rows and this rows should contain Name and Status columns
    Repeater1.DataSource = dataSet;
    Repeater1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: [This is what](https://scontent-b-lhr.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xap1/v/t1.0-9/10405635_1500135106942732_3405316026992011431_n.jpg?oh=7a5f0f9013284e7b59204d5a1abafc9c&oe=5501AED9) i want friend,When i am posting these, those should be displayed like that, do u have a code for this?

Comment: hey thanks friend, should i use repeater without  using container div? could you tell me?

Comment: @Prabath you should use div in your case. You can put whatever elements you want. Create the html markup only for one element, when you see that everything is looking okay, put this markup in the repeater and put <%#Eval("Status") %> and other too. The repeater will multiply the html for every record in data source. If the answer helped you can mark it as correct.

Comment: i pasted upper code on page_load but it says dataset not exists,

Comment: @Prabath obviously because you don't fetch data from you database in dataSet. You need to write 50-100 line more for that. First you need to write query to fetch data, check SqlDataAdapter and method Fill this will fetch it in data set. After that you will put this dataset as DataSource of the repeater. I'm leaving this to you.

Comment: Just a clarification to one of your comments in your answer. CreateChildControls() method is only required when you create server controls by inheriting UserControl class, which is indirectly inheriting from Control class. Then we need to override the CreateChildControls() virtual method in this Control class. If you are just adding controls to the current page you don't need to have a CreateChildControls() method.